# python format error saying index out of range when it isnt

Tags: python, loops, indexing, format

I seem to be having an issue pythons .format() tool. I currently have this code:

```
varno=6
input=product([True,False],repeat = (varno))
string= ({1} or not {2} or not {5} )and (not {1} or {6} )and (not {2} or not {3} )and ({3} or not {4} )and (not {4} or {5} or not {6} )
for i in input:
   print(i)  //prints (True, True, True, True, True, True)
   ans=(string.format(*i))
```

and It returns this error

```
    ans=(string.format(*i))
IndexError: Replacement index 6 out of range for positional args tuple
```

even though there are 6 values in i, so 6 should not be out of range. I have no idea what is going wrong or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

indexes of a list run from 0 to n-1, so the last item in your 6 item list would have an index =5, and the first item in your list would have an index =0